# How do I manipulate variable names based on the calling (Button) sender (button #) calling the method?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a bunch of text boxes in a panel on my C# Winform.  Each row of text boxes are named like this:

> tb1    tbNickName1   comboBox1
>  tb2    tbNickName2   comboBox2
>   tb3    tbNickName3   comboBox3

and so on.

I have a button next to each of the rows of text boxes.  But instead of having the button point to a different event for each button, I want to point the button to just the button1_Click event and have it do all of the processing there.  I know how to do this and all my buttons point to the button1_Click event.

But I need to be able to determine which button it was called from (which I am able to do), but I need to manipulate the name of the text boxes in the event so I can do the processing based on what row I am in/button that I am calling from.

For example, if I am in row number 2 where the tb2    tbNickName2   comboBox2 textboxes are, then I need to be able to have the button1_Click event know this and automatically assign the tb2    tbNickName2   comboBox2 values to the tmp variables that I use in the example below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Button bt = (Button) sender; //will return 'button1'

       string tmpEmail = null;
       string tmpNickName = null;
       string tmpGroup = null;

       //I don't want to hard code the tb1.Text value here, I want to have
       // the namechange based on which (Button) sender it was called from.

       // For example button1 should assign all the
       // tb1    tbNickName1   comboBox1 values

       //If called from button2, then it should assign the
       //tb2    tbNickName2   comboBox2 values instead

       //How can I do this so tb1.Text is based off of the button # that I am 
       //calling for example tb(bt).Text would be cool but that does not work.

       tmpEmail = tb1.Text; //What do I change tb1.Text to based on button #?

       tmpNickName = tbNickName1.Text; //What do I change tbNickName1.Text to?

       tmpGroup = comboBox1.Text;//What do I change comboBox1.Text to?
}
```

I know that I have not explained this very well, but it is the best I can do.

Comment: Use can use the CommandArgument-property of the buttons and evaluate that in your EventHandler.

Comment: Can you please show me a code example on how to do this?

Comment: I postet a little code snippet as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button button = sender as Button;
string buttonIndex = button.Name.Substring(6);
string tempEmail = (this.Controls["tb" + buttonIndex] as TextBox).Text;
string tmpNickName = (this.Controls["tbNickName" + buttonIndex] as TextBox).Text;
string tmpGroup = (this.Controls["comboBox" + buttonIndex] as ComboBox).Text;
```

Comment: string tempEmail = (this.Controls["tb" + buttonIndex] as TextBox).Text; causes a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Comment: So TextBox with name tb + buttonIndex not exist in your WinForm

Comment: I figured out the error.  I changed the line of code to include my panel name and it works fine now:   string tempEmail = (this.panel1.Controls["tb" + buttonIndex] as TextBox).Text;

Comment: this.Text = this.Text; this is very interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (iterating over the controls in the panel) :

```
   //Get the number of the button control (last digit of the name)
   string strNum = bt.Name.Substring(bt.Name.Lenght -2);
   foreach(Control ctrl in myPanel.Controls)
    {
        if(ctrl is ComboBox) {
           if(ctrl.Name.EndsWith(strNum)) {
             //Do Something with your found ComboBox ...
            }
         }
    }
```

Code not tested but should give you an idea ...

Answer (score 0):

On the buttons, you add the CommandArgument-Property which could look something like this

```
bt1.CommandArgument = "1";
bt2.CommandArgument = "2";
```

In your EventHandler, you read the CommandArgument and act accordingly

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button bt = (Button) sender;
        if(bt.CommandArgument == "1") {
            // bt1 was clicked, handle stuff accordingly
        } else if(bt.CommandArgument == "2") {
            // bt2 was clicked..
        } else {
            //handle rest of possible cases
        }
    }
```

It's only pseudo code but I think you can see where this is going. However keep in mind, that your variable-naming is far from optimal. Chose names for your variables and controls that give you any kind of information instead of just naming them with numbers. That would help you a lot if you take a look at the code at a later time and try to understand it. Just like this, try to find meaningful CommanArgument-values, too.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I have so much code that is based on each row of text boxes that I want to assign to my temp variables.  I want to avoid having all that duplicate code in between the different if/else statements.  I want to have one set of code that assigns the text boxes to the temp variables based on what button # is calling the event.

Comment: If the code that should be executed for each case is always the same, then just put it in a different method, set your temp variables according to the CommandArgument and pass those temp variables to the method that is executing your actual code.

Comment: The majority of the code is the same except for the variable names that will change based on which text boxes that I need to assign values from.  It is still a lot of repeat code in a lot of methods and I want to try something more efficient and easier to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

First off, for your own, ours, and anyone else ever looking at your codes sake, change your naming convention.

As for a solution, I would suggest putting references to your checkboxes and text boxes into a dictionary when you construct them. Make the buttons contain the key you used in their `CommandArgument`. Now you can retreive the row by accessing the dictionary.

For instance, in your constructor, you'd add something like this

```
_rowDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Row> {
    { "identifier of first line", new Row { descriptiveNameOfFirstTextBox, descriptiveNameOfFirstTextBox, descriptiveNameOfButton } },
    // ...
};
descriptiveNameOfButton.CommandArgument = "identifier of first line";
```

Then, in your event handler

```
Button senderButton = (Button) sender;
Row r = _rowDictionary[senderButton.CommandArgument];
```

Here, I've used some container class `Row`. You may of may not need it

```
class Row {
    TextBox textBoxForInputOfA { get; set; }
    TextBox textBoxForInputOfB { get; set; }
    Button buttonForDoingWhatItDoes { get; set; }
}
```